# Change cursor position after bracket autocomplete on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Default cursor position after bracket autocomplete in vscode is `inside bracket`.
I want this behavior to position on `right side of bracket`.

#### Default cursor position after bracket autocomplete

```
( )  
 ↑
```

#### Cursor position want to change after bracket autocomplete

```
( )
   ↑
```

I searched for long time, but there's only answer for 'disabling bracket auto complete feature'.

How can I make this work?